# Why is the Authentication state on my login page not persistent as soon as I redirect to login page?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

The auth state of my firebase web app is not preserved while moving between web pages after I have deployed my web app on firebase hosting.I am using persistence state as 'session'.While I was using brackets live hosting it was working fine.But now after deploying in firebase hosting, the web app while getting redirected from login page to dashboard the auth state of a user is getting lost.

The domain is the default domain provided by fb and it is whitelisted in fb auth page as well as google developer console browser key section.

The auth state is lost every time the page is redirected after successful  login.How do I achieve persistent auth state in fb hosting ?

Comment: Are you sticking to the same domain on redirect (if you change subdomain the user will not be accessible from a different subdomain)? Also are you using `onAuthStateChanged` listener to detect a user is signed in?